# For every $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ , does there exist a ring automorphism $\psi$ on $\mathbb C[x]$ of order $n$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

For every $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ , does there exist a ring automorphism $\psi$ on $\mathbb C[x]$ such that $\psi^n=\psi \circ... n $ times is the identity  automorphism but $\psi^r$ is not identity for any $0<r<n$ i.e. $\psi$ has order $n$  ?

Answer (score 1):

Take the map $x\mapsto\zeta x$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of $1$